# Calibre: how to avoid unnecessary new pages (page breaks) when converting ePub/AZW3 to PDF?

Tags: pdf, epub, calibre

I'm trying to convert a azw3 to PDF, using Calibre.

The pages in calibre looks fine:

[image]

However, when convert to PDF, the pages becomes

[image]

To be specific, code and images generate too much unnecessary new pages. How can I avoid them?

Thanks

Comment: How are you converting the documents?

Comment: @GuyGastineau default setting, I didn't change too much regarding page layout.

Comment: you're using tools in Calibre to do the conversion? That is what I was really asking.

Comment: @GuyGastineau yes. It's calibre 's convert to PDF feature.

Comment: I just pandoc for that type of work.  Hopefully you get some good help.  Good luck!